# How to get the number of routes in Navigator's stack

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to know if the current page is the last page in the Navigator Stack and calling `Navigator.pop()` at this point will close the app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code to check if the route is the first :

```
ModalRoute.of(context).isFirst
```

so the full code will be

```
if(! ModalRoute.of(context).isFirst)
Navigator.pop();
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't close the app it destroys the last route shows a black screen.

you can close the app using this: [Flutter how to programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app)

and you can't access the stack or history because it's private in Navigator class `Navigator._history` but you can use this workaround to check if the current route is the last one or not:

```dart
Future<bool> isCurrentRouteFirst(BuildContext context) {
    var completer = new Completer<bool>();
    Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
      completer.complete(route.isFirst);
      return true;
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the source of the `AppBar` widget.

```dart
final ModalRoute<dynamic>? parentRoute = ModalRoute.of(context);
final bool canPop = parentRoute?.canPop ?? false;
```

When `canPop` is `false`, you are on the root screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to handle something before the application exits. Like showing an confirm dialog you could use `WillPopScope`.

Example

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _showDialog,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("This is the first page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _showDialog() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Are you sure?"),
        content: Text("You want to exit app"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("Yes"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("No"),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          )
        ],
      );
    }) ?? false;
  }
```

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a better answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000349/i-open-the-app-through-the-notification-and-want-to-keep-it-open-after-the-user/58004051#58004051 that wants to open the main page when the route stack is empty.